# Google sheet vlookup and multiple importrange n arrayformula to return specific value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I am trying to combine the array formula with vlookup and import range to return specific values from three columns in different sheet like the below

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(C4,IMPORT RANGE("URL","Autoparts!A:AC"),{5,29,10},0))
```

C4 is the cell that has the value I'm looking for.
---
---
{5,29,10} These are the columns where to look for the needed values.`
---
---

the import range sheets have more than 30k rows with 30 columns, how to split the import range to avoid the "results too large" error?

---

**NSP PARTS**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D8n_i-HXqgmt54OOVYpu6Y57cXbqUbV0E9bA2PyAM6Q/edit?usp=sharing

---

**TARGET SHEET**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZIe1gr0Jf_l4fBHRwW9AXEKdvQLPWZ-kNgMly76036w/edit#gid=0

I tried many solutions, but I am not able to get it to work

**Any help is really appreciated.**

Comment: I tried many solutions like the one below, but I am not able to get it to work  
`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(C9,{IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hi_Lu8Igm_c2XbQA9SBRI5pl0G9fjuqAhQGkw_0lCqc/edit#gid=0","Autoparts!A1:AC15000");`

`IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hi_Lu8Igm_c2XbQA9SBRI5pl0G9fjuqAhQGkw_0lCqc/edit#gid=0","Autoparts!A15000:AC30000");`

`IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hi_Lu8Igm_c2XbQA9SBRI5pl0G9fjuqAhQGkw_0lCqc/edit#gid=0","Autoparts!A:AC")},{5,29,10},0))`

Comment: Can you please simplify the exact problem you are having because multiple questions in one question often gets a question closed if they are not really directly related to the specific programming issue. You can provide a simplified set of data to demonstrate as simply as possible the issue and your desired output

Comment: Ask exactly 1 question per post. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Comment: Don't share complete full bulky spreadsheet links. Use markdown tables instead.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.